# Dynamic variable to set OFFSET (mySQL, php)

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, offset

Appreciate any help, what am I doing wrong? Undeclared variable: $offset

```
$offset = 1;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM links order by payout desc limit $offset, 1';
```

Comment: This can't be the actual code that produces this error messages as with single quotes there wouldn't be any variable replacement anyway, you'd just get a literal `... limit $offset, 1` in your `$sql` variable ...

Comment: It's not the code I wanted to use. But this is the code that is giving that error. I don't understand why it's an undeclared variable?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use variable substitution in strings to build SQL queries like that. It creates SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Use PDO or mysqli, and supply the variables as data e.g.:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from links ORDER BY payout DESC LIMIT :offset, 1');

if ($stmt->execute(array(':offset' => $offset)) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: You can do so if you escape, in this case it's a number so just use intval.

Answer (score -2):

One thing to mention, it seems you wrote variable inline in single quotes, variables can only be recognized in double quotes

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM links order by payout desc limit ' . intval($offset) . ', 1';
```

Comment: congratulations you've just created an SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: If the offset is defined as 1, there is no vulnerability is there? And to avoid it if it is a get variable, use intval($offset).

Comment: In that singular situation, yes casting to int would remove the risk, but as a general rule parameterised queries are considered a better solution as they can protect queries with any kind of input variables.